# Swift , Identing Table Views each row gets more indented

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXG1O.png)

I am trying to make it so each name of the characters indents more and more with each row so from left then the next row goes a little more to the right and then the next row goes a little more to the right.

I simply can not figure out why I can't indent my labels one by one. Any help is appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var Dwarves = ["Sleepy", "Sneezy", "Bashful", "Dopy", "Grumpy", "Doc", "Happy", "Sad"]
    var imagess = ["Sleepy", "Sneezy", "Bashful", "Dopy", "Grumpy", "Doc", "Happy", "Sad"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Dwarves.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.CellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.CellView.frame.height / 2
        cell.Label.text = Dwarves[indexPath.row]
        cell.CharcterImage.image = UIImage(named: 

imagess[indexPath.row])
        cell.CharcterImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.CharcterImage.frame.height / 2

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath.) -> Int {

    }
}
```

I tried to use the `indentationLevelforRowAt` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 import UIKit


class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var CellView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var CharcterImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Label:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TableView:UITableView!





override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Show what you tried and explain what result you get.

Comment: The results all seem to be the same only one that seems to have any effect maybe I'm writing it wrong I search Xcode library for anything closes I got was var indentationLevel: Int
The indentation level of the cell’s content.
var indentationWidth: CGFloat
The width for each level of indentation of a cell's content.

Comment: [Edit] your question and show your attempted implementation of `indentationLevelForRowAt`. Right now you've left it blank in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primitive way to do it would be to prefix the string with spaces. Here I use an indentation level of two spaces.

```
cell.Label.text = "\(String(repeating: " " , count: indexPath.row*2))\(Dwarves[indexPath.row])")
```

Comment: Surprisingly the moment I read this it just clicked that this is primitive but for what i'm doing ill keep my eye out for better methods but this just worked like you think it would. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`indentationLevelforRowAt` allows you to display the table rows in a hierarchal / tree-view type format. But you want to indent just a part of your cell. Therefore I think you should play with your constraints.

One of possible solutions is create a leading constraint for label and in `cellForRowAt` method write something like this:

```
cell.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = 5 * indexPath.row
```

Comment: I attempted to use this but i had no luck.

Comment: @PhillipYates Can you explain why?

Comment: I am getting Value type customTableViewCell has no member labelLeadingConstraint. I have tryed to find something close but it seems that every time i call for it my code wants nothing to do with it.

Comment: @PhillipYates Have you created IBOutlet for constraint in your cell?

Comment: I do not understand an Iboutlet for constraints like the ones you make on the main storyboard? I made all my outlets for label and images and views. So little confused.

Comment: @PhillipYates You can create IBOutlets for your constraints like for buttons. Example you can see in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWktmOpXtKk

Comment: I’m at work right now but never seen that before going to have to give it a try will prolly help in the future thank you. I’ll let you know how it goes

Comment: @PhillipYates Okay, I'm waiting :)